# Tensorflow - log to an existing log-file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I use Tensorflow-CPU in Python and I want to log all the logging-output, that is produced by the program, into a file.

So I setup my logger, where normal Debug-Messages are printed (to the console and to the log-file).

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    handlers=[
        logging.StreamHandler(),
        logging.FileHandler('log_file')
    ]
)
```

All calls to `logger.debug(message)` are visible in my log-file.

Somehow my goal is to log the Tensorflow-Output, that is printed on the console, to my log-file additionally. To be specific I want to log for example these TF-messages into my file:

```
2023-07-18 11:11:20,123412: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized 
with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical 
operations:  AVX2 FMA To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:108] Allocation of 18599850000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```